# Why only 3 last rep events shown and no "view more"?

Tags: support, reputation

Usually I have this picture (as on my [Craft CMS profile](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/250/nicael) now). 4 last events and "view more".

> [image]

But now in [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael) there on Meta only 3 last events and no "view more".

> [image]

Could anyone explain me why?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, yes, looks like dupe. Don't you know the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Not really.  Never encountered it before so never really tried to figure it out.  The assumptions made in the dup seem to be the best guesses.